# Confusion about UnboundLocalError: local variable 'number_sum' referenced before assignment when manually applying decorator

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, scope, closures, python-decorators

Was experimenting with applying memoization decorator to recursive functions using standard python @decorator notation, which worked beautifully.  According to much of the documentation I've read, these code examples are supposed to be equivalent:

```
# letting python decorator mechanism take care of wrapping your function with the decorator function
@decorator
def func(): . . .

print(func(arg))
```

AND

```
# manually wrapping the decorator function around the function
func = decorator(func)
print(func(arg))
```

When I do this, however, I get an UnboundLocalError on func.

If I change the code to

```
new_name = decorator(func)
print(new_name(func))
```

The code runs, but the decorator is only applied to the first call and not to any of the recursive calls (this did NOT surprise me), but I don't get any error messages either.

What seems weird to me, however, is the original error message itself.
If I experiment further and try the following code:

```
new_name = decorator(func)
func = new_name
print(func(arg))
```

I get the same error ON THE SAME LINE AS BEFORE (????)
In fact, if I form a chain of these assignments, with `func = several_names_later`
I still get the same error on the ORIGINAL line
Can anyone explain what is going on, and why I'm getting the error, and why it seems that the error is disconnected from the location of the variable in question?

As requested, here is most of the actual code (with just one of the recursive functions), hope it's not too much . . .

```
import functools 
 
def memoize(fn): 
  cache = dict() 

  @functools.wraps(fn) 
  def memoizer(*args):
    print(args)
    if args not in cache: 
      cache[args] = fn(*args) 
    return cache[args] 
 
  return memoizer

#@memoize   
def number_sum(n): 
  '''Returns the sum of the first n numbers''' 
  assert(n >= 0), 'n must be >= 0' 
  if n == 0:
    return 0
  else:
    return n + number_sum(n-1)

def main():
  # Book I'm reading claims this can be done but I get error instead:
  number_sum = memoize(number_sum) # this is the flagged line
  print(number_sum(300))
  #UnboundLocalError: local variable 'number_sum' referenced before assignment

  # When I do this instead, only applies decorator to first call, as I suspected
  # but works otherwise: no errors and correct - but slow - results
  # No complaints about number_sum
  wrapped_number_sum = memoize(number_sum)
  print(wrapped_number_sum(300))

  # This is what is odd:  
  # When I do any version of this, I get the same error as above, but always on
  # the original line, flagging number_sum as the problem
  wrapped_number_sum = memoize(number_sum) # the flagged line, no matter what
  number_sum = wrapped_number_sum
  print(number_sum(300))

  OR even:
  wrapped_number_sum = memoize(number_sum) # still the flagged line
  another_variable = wrapped_number_sum
  number_sum = another_variable
  print(number_sum(300))

if __name__ == '__main__': 
  main()
```

I am more than a little mystified at this.

Comment: “but the decorator is only applied to the first call and not to any of the recursive calls” — it makes sense to me, because the decorator is assigned to a different-named *[probably] local variable*, unrelated to any recursive usages.

Comment: Anyway, post the *full code* (as a *minimal* reproduction case) causing the UnboundReferenceError. The function is probably not declared in the same scope. This code should also *actually match* the reported error, which should in turn be reported verbatim..

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that. I expected the first result (that it wouldn't be applied to the recursive calls), but I didn't expect the error.